# Hanging Indent for caption in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, caption, indent

I want create caption with hanging indent for a long sentence neatly just like below:

[image: Example 1]

But, I always get like sentence below every time and I need to adjust the indent manually. Even, I already adjust manually it cannot be perfect like sentence above.

[image: Example]

I hope there is idea for solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the Caption style's indent. If you are going to have more than 9 figures, allow room for the extra digit.